# Angular Service Member Variable Not Accessible in Unit Tests

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I am trying to test my Angular service, and part of what the service does is load a JSON file that is used as configuration for the service. I have confirmed in the tests (through `console.log`) that the way I am mocking the HTTP.get call to get the configuration is working and is returning the mocked config object:

```
// mocking the loading of the configuration in the beforeEach
authenticationService.loadInternalAuthModuleConfiguration();
const req = httpTestingController.expectOne('./internal-config.json');
req.flush({
    redirectStorage: 'testing-redirect',
    forbiddenStorage: 'testing-forbidden',
    useAuthServerInDevelopment: true,
});
httpTestingController.verify();
```

When I `console.log` in the `loadInternalAuthModuleConfiguration` function, I see the object and information from the `req.flush` shown above. In the `load` function, it takes that configuration object and sets its value to a private variable in the service:

```
loadInternalAuthModuleConfiguration() {
    return this._http
        .get(this.authConfig.internalAuthModuleConfigUrl)
        .toPromise()
        .then((configData: any) => {
            this.internalConfigData = { ...configData };
            this.internalConfigSubject.next(this.internalConfigData);
            this.setPrivateClassVariables();
        })
        .catch((err: any) => {
            this.internalConfigData = null;
            this.internalConfigSubject.next(this.internalConfigData);
        });
}
```

Again, `console.log` shows that in the `.then` method above that the `configData` comes back properly and that it is set to be the `this.internalConfigData`. My problem comes in the next step.

I want to check that I can access a value from that `configData` object after it's been set. (Remember that I ran the `load` function in the `beforeEach`.) I have a function in the service, `getInternalConfig` and `getInternalConfigValueByKey` that will either return the entire config object or a value for the specified key. When I run this in a test, I get undefined for the `internalConfigData` object and for the value of the passed in key.

```
it('should be using testing-redirect as the redirectStorage', () => {
    const configObj = authenticationService.getInternalConfig();
    const redirectStorage = authenticationService.getInternalConfigValueByKey('redirectStorage');
    expect(redirectStorage).toBe('testing-redirect');
});
```

That test should pass. If I `console.log` the `internalConfigData` object in the `load` function I can see the object I've given it. I'm not sure why it seems that `this.internalConfigData` is losing its data somewhere between `beforeEach` and when my test runs.

What am I missing here to make sure that this test runs correctly and passes?

### Edit

Here is the `TestBed.configureTestingModule` for reference as well:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
    providers: [
        AuthenticationService,
        { provide: AuthenticationConfig, useValue: mockAuthConfig },
        { provide: OidcConfigService, useValue: mockOidcConfigService },
        { provide: OidcSecurityService, useValue: mockOidcSecurityService },
        { provide: localStorage, useValue: mockLocalStorage },
    ],
});
```

### Edit 2

Here's the entire `beforeEach` and the related test:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    mockOidcConfigService = jasmine.createSpyObj(['load']);
    mockOidcSecurityService = jasmine.createSpyObj(['getIsAuthorized']);

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
        providers: [
            AuthenticationService,
            { provide: AuthenticationConfig, useValue: mockAuthConfig },
            { provide: OidcConfigService, useValue: mockOidcConfigService },
            { provide: OidcSecurityService, useValue: mockOidcSecurityService },
            { provide: localStorage, useValue: mockLocalStorage },
        ],
    });

    httpTestingController = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
    authenticationService = TestBed.get(AuthenticationService);

    store = {};

    authenticationService.loadInternalAuthModuleConfiguration();
    const req = httpTestingController.expectOne('./internal-config.json');
    req.flush({
        redirectStorage: 'testing-redirect',
        forbiddenStorage: 'testing-forbidden',
        useAuthServerInDevelopment: true,
    });
    httpTestingController.verify();
});

it('should be using testing-redirect as the redirectStorage', () => {
    const configObj = authenticationService.getInternalConfig();
    const redirectStorage = authenticationService.getInternalConfigValueByKey('redirectStorage');
    expect(redirectStorage).toBe('testing-redirect');
});
```

Comment: Maybe you have multiple instances of your service. And only one of them gets the mock value.  What does your providers array look like?

Comment: @Isaac I added the `TestBed.configureTestingModule` with the providers array to the bottom of the question.

Comment: First off I have using the testbed and recommend not using it. But since you want to, my next question is how are you getting a handle to the service to ask it questions?

Comment: @JosephEames I added a little more code to show that. I will say though that I'm not using the `TestBed` for any specific reason other than it's what was in the test file generated by the CLI. If there's a better way to do it, I'm open to it.

Comment: This is one of the terrible problems with the CLI. test files by default use the testbed. that's dumb. All angular code (outside of templates) is simple JS classes. you can test them using basic jasmine/karma. So the only need for the testbed is if you want to test a template with a component.

Comment: in addition, I'm not even sure what this test is testing. a test should be a statement of the functionality of a piece of your application. When you were designing the authenticationService, is one of the things you realized it needed was "should use testing-redirect as the redirectStorage"? I'll bet it wasn't. I'll bet it was something more like "it should use the redirectStorage it was given"

I'm also a bit confused. does this test test the getInternalConfig method or the loadInternalAuthModuleConfiguration method?

Comment: also, why do you have the first line of code in the it block? you're not asserting anything on it. Is it the result of a temporal dependency? if not, move the tests on it to their own it()

Comment: @JosephEames I forgot to remove the first line of that test after I was debugging. I removed that from the real test. I agree on what I was looking to test as well, the naming you suggest there is much better. Finally, I want to test both of those methods.

Comment: ok. that makes more sense. Good deal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that you transform http Observable to Promise and your test becomes asynchronous. It means that by the time the code reaches `it` statement your service doesn't have data resolved yet.

If you used Observable it would passed:

```
loadInternalAuthModuleConfiguration() {
  return this.http
    .get(this.authConfig.internalAuthModuleConfigUrl)
    .subscribe((configData: any) => {
      this.internalConfigData = {...configData};
      this.internalConfigSubject.next(this.internalConfigData);
      this.setPrivateClassVariables();
    }, (err: any) => {
      this.internalConfigData = null;
      this.internalConfigSubject.next(this.internalConfigData);
    });
}
```

If you still want to convert observable to promise you have to wait all microtasks to be executed:

```
import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';  
...
beforeEach(async(() => {
  ...
}));
```

Comment: In this case it has to be converted to a promise, so using `async` around the `beforeEach` worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: just curious, why does it require being a promise?